# Same css code but different output

Tags: html, css

I have here one file.

My html looked like this:

```
<div id="banner">
<div id="bannerTextBlue"> <h1> lorem ipsum </h1> </div> 
<div id="bannerTextYellow"> <h1> dolor sit amet. </h1> </div>
</div>
```

And my css is this:

```
#banner{
  background: #FFF;
  width: 1140px;
  margin:30px auto 0;
  border: 12px solid #323232;
  height: 448px;
  position:relative;
}

#bannerTextBlue{
  height: 90px;
  background: #027cd6;
  width: 600px;
  right: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 90px;
}

#bannerTextBlue h1{
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 88px;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#bannerTextYellow{
  height: 60px;
  background: #f4b437;
  width: 500px;
  right: 0px;
  top: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

#bannerTextYellow h1{
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 35px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

But the output is different. It supposed to look alright in Chrome but in Firefox it is destroyed. Not sure where is the glitch here. Please help? Is there something wrong with my css structure?

Comment: Looks fine to me. What is the issue? -- Your code as a executable sample: http://jsfiddle.net/WwNdp/

Comment: its looking same on all browers so can you tell us what exactly the problem....

Comment: What is that difference? I see none to be honest.

Comment: can't see the difference in Chrome and FF

Comment: looks the same for me in both FF and Chrome... (*text over other text.. but the same in both cases*)

Comment: it's fine FF, Chrome and safari what's prob...

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want a `font-size` larger than the `line-height` ?

This makes the second line (*in the blue box*) to overlap the first... (*if that is what you mean with **destroyed***)

(*but it happens the same in all browsers..*)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, there are differences between browsers. Check the version of your Firefox. I'm not sure that this will work, but try to install a newer version of Firefox. Or to make sure that it will work anytime and any browser, there is a browser packet (i'm not sure about the term), but it will determine the user's browser and it will automatically adjust to what is the user's browser. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Differences between browsers can be caused by the default settings in those browsers.

You're not specifying a font, so if FF has a different default font than Chrome, the result will be different.

There is also the minimum font size, but I guess that won't be a problem with your example here.